# Arrays and Searching Them

Tags: c++, arrays, string, debugging

I am trying to finish my final debugging tonight. My problem is that I have been writing this code for a couple days and it has a few problems.  [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833534/how-to-fix-error-that-leads-to-program-crash#comment12543685_9833534)

It now compiles and does not crash, but there are a few issues with my functions not working properly (or at all).

```
#include <iostream>              
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

string bookTitle [50];
string bookAuthor [50];
int loadData (string pathname);         
int showall (int counter);
int authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50]);




int main ()

{  
    string pathname;
    int counter=0;
    char choice;

    cout<<"Input the name of the file to be accessed: ";
    cin>>pathname;
    loadData (pathname);
    showall (counter);

    cout<<"\n\n\n\n What would you like to do \n (A for Author Search , T for Title Search, Q to quit):";
    cin>>choice;

    while (choice != 'Q' , choice != 'q')
    {
          if (choice == 'A', choice == 'a')
          {
                    int authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50], char choice);
          }

          if (choice == 'T', choice == 't')
          {
                     int   titleSearch (string bookTitle [50], char choice);   
          }   


    }

    cout<<"Press <Enter> to Exit";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();      
    return 0;              

    cout<<"Press <Enter> to Exit";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();      
    return 0;                
}


int loadData (string pathname) // Loads data from infile into arrays
{
    fstream infile; 
    int counter = 0;
    infile.open(pathname.c_str()); //Opens file from user input in main
    if( infile.fail() )
     {
         cout << "File failed to open";
         return 0;
     }   

     while (!infile.eof())
     {

           infile >> bookTitle [counter] ;  //takes input and puts into parallel arrays
           infile >> bookAuthor [counter];
           counter++;
     }

     infile.close();
}

int showall (int counter)        // shows input in title(author) format
{

     cout<<bookTitle<<"("<<bookAuthor<<")";   

}

void authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50], char choice) // Function to search Author Array
{
     string target = "";
     cout<<"Which author would you like to search for: "<<target; //input
     for (int count = 0; count++;)
     {
         if(bookAuthor[count] == target) //tests input against array and outputs result
         {
                              cout<<bookTitle[count]<<bookAuthor[count];
         }
     }

}



void titleSearch (string bookTitle [50], char choice) // Function to Serch Title Array
{
     string target = "";
     cout<<"Which author would you like to search for: "<<target; //input
     for (int count = 0; count++;)
     {
         if(bookAuthor[count] == target) //tests input against array and outputs result
         {
                              cout<<bookTitle[count]<<bookAuthor[count];
         }
     }

}
```

Latest Version , no major improvements. I am having trouble getting the functions to work after the menu selection. ShowAll seems to work but outputs hex.  Thanks again everyone!

```
#include <iostream>              
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

string bookTitle [50];
string bookAuthor [50];
int loadData (string pathname);         
int showall (int counter);
void authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50]);
void titleSearch (string bookTitle [50]);



int main ()

{  
    string pathname;
    int counter=0;
    char choice;

    cout<<"Input the name of the file to be accessed: ";
    cin>>pathname;
    loadData (pathname);
    showall (counter);

    cout<<"\n\n\n\n What would you like to do \n (A for Author Search , T for Title Search, Q to quit):";
    cin>>choice;

    while (choice != 'Q'|| choice != 'q')
    {
          if (choice == 'A'|| choice == 'a')
          {
                   void authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50], char choice);
          }

          if (choice == 'T'|| choice == 't')
          {
                    void titleSearch (string bookTitle [50], char choice);   
          }   


    }

    cout<<"Press <Enter> to Exit";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();      
    return 0;              

}


int loadData (string pathname) // Loads data from infile into arrays
{
    fstream infile; 
    int counter = 0;
    infile.open(pathname.c_str()); //Opens file from user input in main
    if( infile.fail() )
     {
         cout << "File failed to open";
         return 0;
     }   

     while (!infile.eof())
     {

           infile >> bookTitle [counter] ;  //takes input and puts into parallel arrays
           infile >> bookAuthor [counter];
           counter++;
     }

     infile.close();
}

int showall (int counter)        // shows input in title(author) format
{

     cout<<bookTitle<<"("<<bookAuthor<<")";   

}

void authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50], char choice) // Function to search Author Array
{
     string target = "";
     cout<<"Which author would you like to search for: "<<target; //input
     for (int count = 0; count++;)
     {
         if(bookAuthor[count] == target)
         {
                              cout<<bookTitle[count]<<bookAuthor[count];
         }
     }

}



void titleSearch (string bookTitle [50], char choice) // Function to Serch Title Array
{
     string target = "";
     cout<<"Which title would you like to search for: "<<target; //input
     for (int count = 0; count++;)
     {
         if(bookAuthor[count] == target) //tests input against array and outputs reults
         {
                              cout<<bookTitle[count]<<bookAuthor[count];
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: You might want to be more explicit with your comma operator. Use && or || instead.

Comment: Please mark this as homework, I know you're previous post mentioned it, but this one does not.

Also, a hint:  if you select the wrong choice how can I choose again?

Comment: thanks for marking this as HW

Comment: What would be the best way to get the function to return to the while statement after the function completes. BTW I cant get the searches to work properly

Comment: The `while-loop` in your search function will never end if your data file is formatted incorrectly. Check that and see my answer below.

Comment: changed it to  'if', I really would like to use a goto type function to make it return to the part where the user inputs what they want to do. But alas goto is bad c++ form.

Comment: I made a mistake in my last comment. You need to *fix* your prototype parameters at the top of your source file. They're inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator should be replaced with logical `and` or `or`, `&&` and `||` respectively. See [uses of the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator). Also, `authorSearch` is a `void` function. If you want to call `authorSearch`, simple write `authorSearch(...)` instead of `int authorSearch(...)`.

Additionally, you need to make sure your prototypes are consistent with your implementations. `int authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50])` is not the same as `void authorSearch (string bookAuthor [50], char choice)`. You've mismatched their types *and* their parameters.

Comment: Just pointing out that `&&` and `||` are the logical `and` and `or`. The bitwise ones are `&` and `|`.

Comment: If I get rid of the type specifier in front of authorsearch it will not compile.

Comment: You need to fix your prototype definitions at the top of your source file. They're inconsistent with the implementations you provided at the bottom of your source file.

Comment: they are now currently fixed, thank you. Does anyone have any Idea why im getting some sort of hex code back for the showall function?

Comment: `bookTitle` and `bookAuthor` are string arrays, not strings. You need to index them with `bookTitle[index]`. Printing `bookTitle` prints the memory location of the beginning array.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `showall()` function outputs hex because you can't display arrays that way, you need some kind of loop. It's just printing the *starting address* of each array.

2) In your search functions you never read the `target` string from the user.

3) These `for()` loops will never execute:

```
for (int count = 0; count++;)
{
    ...
}
```

You set `count` to `0` and then test the value before incrementing. The test fails and the loop body isn't executed.

4) Take care when you fix the `for()` loops. I don't see any tests to prevent using an invalid index past the (hardcoded) size of your arrays.